# How to find the value in the row?

Tags: javascript

I use the Retool tool to build a dashboard.
I import my data from a google sheet and I would like to be able to make transformation statistics from the data.

From this

```
data = {{ query1.data.map(row => row['Subscriber'])}}
```

I have the following data coming out:

```
["NON","NON","NON","NON","OUI","OUI","NON","NON","NON","NON","NON","NON","OUI","NON","NON","NON","NON","OUI","NON","NON","NON","NON"]
```

I would like to calculate the number of OUI and the number of NON.

I would also like the percentage of YES and NO to the total data

Can you help me?

Comment: Have you heard of ```Array.prototype.reduce()```? That is perfect for this use case.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far and where *specifically* you're getting stuck in your attempt? Stack Overflow generally won't write your code *for* you - see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a frequency map, by reducing the list of "NON" and "OUI" terms with an object.

```js
const
  data = ["NON", "NON", "NON", "NON", "OUI", "OUI", "NON", "NON", "NON", "NON", "NON", "NON", "OUI", "NON", "NON", "NON", "NON", "OUI", "NON", "NON", "NON", "NON"],
  n = data.length,
  frequency = data.reduce((acc, val) =>
    ({ ...acc, [val]: (acc[val] ?? 0) + 1 }), {});

console.log(`Frequency: ${JSON.stringify(frequency)}`);

Object.entries(frequency).forEach(([ key, value ]) =>
  console.log(`${key} = ${value}/${n} | ${(value/n*100).toFixed(2)}%`));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```